# STI column type not being filled

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, rubyonjets

While using Ruby on Jets I defined a superclass:

```rb
class Transfer < ActiveRecord::Base; end
```

and it's subclasses:

```rb
class Transfers::External < Transfer; end

class Transfers::Internal < Transfer; end
```

When I try to save the class I got a error because the column type is null:

```
#> t = Transfers::Internal.new
#> t.save
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR: null value in column "type" violates not-null constraint
#> t.type
nil
```

Any guesses?

Comment: Maybe you have overwritten `inheritance_column` somewhere. Check `Transfers::Internal.inheritance_column` as a sanity check.

Comment: I didn't overwrite it, but I will check if the Ruby on jets is...